# PHP putting last inserted row into a session

Tags: php

I'm working on a school project, and I'm currently working on a form.
I'm trying to insert the last inserted row from a table in my database into a session, so I can reuse the info when they want to go back to the form to adapt something.

So the data is being inserted into the database, but when I try to put the variable $insertedGegvens into a session, it returns null, and I don't understand why.
I currently have this:

PDO:

```
public function selectById($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `gegevens` WHERE `id` = :id";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
      $stmt->execute();
  }

  public function insert($data) {
    $errors = $this->validate( $data );
    if (empty($errors)) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `gegevens` 
                        (`naam`, `gemeente`, `postcode`, `adres`, 
                        `huisnr`, `email`, `tel`) 
                VALUES (:naam, :gemeente, :postcode, :adres, 
                        :huisnr, :email, :tel)";
      $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindValue(':naam', $data['naam']);
      $stmt->bindValue(':gemeente', $data['gemeente']);
      $stmt->bindValue(':postcode', $data['postcode']);
      $stmt->bindValue(':adres', $data['adres']);
      $stmt->bindValue(':huisnr', $data['huisnr']);
      $stmt->bindValue(':email', $data['email']);
      $stmt->bindValue(':tel', $data['tel']);
      if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return $this->selectById($this->pdo->lastInsertId()); //insert returns last row inserted through function selectById
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function validate( $data ){
    $errors = [];
    if (!isset($data['naam'])) {
      $errors['naam'] = 'Gelieve een naam in te vullen';
    }
    if (!isset($data['gemeente'])) {
      $errors['gemeente'] = 'Gelieve een gemeente in te vullen';
    }
    if (!isset($data['postcode'])) {
      $errors['postcode'] = 'Gelieve een postcode in te vullen';
    }
    if (empty($data['adres']) ){
      $errors['adres'] = 'Gelieve een adres in te vullen';
    }
    if (empty($data['huisnr']) ){
      $errors['huisnr'] = 'Gelieve een huisnummer in te vullen';
    }
    if (empty($data['email']) ){
      $errors['email'] = 'Gelieve een email in te vullen';
    }
    if (empty($data['tel']) ){
      $errors['tel'] = 'Gelieve een telefoonnummer in te vullen';
    }
    return $errors;
  }
```

```
  if($_POST['action'] == 'toCheckout'){
    $insertedGegevens = $this->orderDAO->insert($_POST);

    //trying to insert the info it just inserted into a SESSION['user'] so I can reuse this info when user returns to form
    $_SESSION['user'] = array();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $insertedGegevens;
    //$_SESSION['user'] returns null

    if (!$insertedGegevens) {
      $error = $this->orderDAO->validate($_POST);
      $this->set('errors', $error);
    }
    $_SESSION['user'] = array();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $insertedGegevens;
    header('Location: index.php?page=checkout');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I assume `$this->orderDAO->insert` is the `insert` method you show

Comment: Yes, I insert the POST info with that line.

Comment: Your method `selectById` that is called by `return $this->selectById(...` ... doesn't actually return anything for the other return to return.

Comment: So i need to add `return` to ```$stmt->execute()```?

Comment: don't forge to execute `session_start()` before you use the $8SESSION varable

Comment: If you're getting `$insertedGegevens` and you are not able to store it in session then it means you didn't start the session yet.